# Hi-lo game with a twist

Tags: c++

Stuck on this C++ assignment. It's a typical Hi-lo game, where a random number is generated from 1-100 by computer, and several N players have to guess the number. The number of players is 3-5 players. If the input is smaller/larger than the number, the range will change for the next player accordingly (e.g., if the secret number is 10, and Player 1 inputs 5, then the range displayed for the next Player is 5-100 instead of 1-100).

The problem is that the assignment requires that G number of games (where G > = N, the number of players) is played. The number of games, unlike the number of players, if not restricted (so as long as it is more than the number of players it's OK). On top of that, each game has to start with a different numbered player (e.g., Game 1 starts with Player 1, then Player 2....Player N, while Game 2 starts with Player 2, Player 3....Player N, back to Player 1).

They keep inputting guesses until one gets the secret number, and then the score is recorded for that specific player.

How do I code the score recording with the player number changing every game? I'm a beginner and was stuck for a whole day... I've attached what I have. 
NOTE*: Only using **if, if-else, while, do-while, for, break, continue and switch** statements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int N, G;
    cout << "How many players (3-5)?" << endl;
    cin >> N;
    while (N < 3 || N > 5){
        cout << "Number of players must be 3-5! Try again.";
        cin >> N;
    } //Make sure 3-5 players
    cout << "How many games?" << endl;
    cin >> G;
    while (G < N) {
        cout << "At least " << N << "games! Try again.";
        cin >> G;
    }//Make sure G>=N

srand(N * G); //initalizing RNG

int g, secret, x, lo, hi; //repeat for N players for G games, define secret, input x, lower bound and higher bound
for (g = 1; g <= G; g++) {
    secret = rand() % 100 + 1; //secret number is an interger between 1 and 100
    lo = 1;
    hi = 100;
    cout << "Game #" << g << ":";
    while (x != secret) {
        cout << "Player" << (g - 1) % N + 1 << ", make a guess (" << lo << "-" << hi << "):";
        cin >> x; //ask starting player to guess the number...?
        while (x < lo || x > hi) {
            cout << "Guess must be between" << lo << "and" << hi << "Please try again.";
            cin >> x; //ask again if they input not within lo-hi range
        }
        if (x < secret) {
            cout << "Your guess is Lo.";
            lo = x;
            g++; // so that the player number gets updated
        }
        else if (x>secret) {
            cout << "Your guess is Hi.";
            hi = x;
            g++;// so that the player number gets updated
        }
        else {
            cout << "Boom! Player" << (g - 1) % N + 1 << "loses.";      
        }//get out of loop and begin new game, but HOW DO WE SAVE THE SCORE?! :(
    }
}//each game is played

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `wins[playerID]++`, basically. an array of ints with an entry for every player, counting how many times they've won.

Comment: If you are not expected to use arrays, you can do the ugly. make 5 variables, player1wins, player2wins and use switch case to increase them.

Comment: OH THAT MAKES SO MUCH SENSE! Thanks, I think I've got this now!

Answer (score 1):

Because this is homework, I will not give you the code. However, here is the logic you should start with.

Do you need this stored between executions of the program itself? If it is going to need to save the score *after the program is closed*, you need to use a file. Look up [C++ File IO](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=c%2B%2B%20file%20io&t=canonical).

If it does NOT need to save the score after the program is closed, you can use a *data structure* that is declared outside the scope of the variable. Some options to consider would be a **struct** (for storing multiple pieces of information in one object), a **vector** or **array** (for storing sequential pieces of information, such as each time played, or storing a group of players), or a custom **class/object** for some more complex setups. This is not something I can help you decide. You will need to look up each of those and make your decision.

Since this is homework, you will have been taught everything you need to write this program so far in the class and book. Reference your textbook, and talk to your professor if you're really stuck - that's what he's there for.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your quick response - but I haven't learnt any of that so I am not sure how to use those arrays, but will research into it. Yes I will talk to him soon but thought I'd try external sources since it's 3am!

Comment: Ah, well, I applaud your research efforts! All the best to you regarding this project. For future reference, this type of question often isn't considered the best fit for the site...they're usually closed and/or downvoted. See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for a lot of excellent information on how to ask a good StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't understood you good.

Make table of players and next choose order of rounds. Then you can save players score status and starting new games with new orders of ansewering